# Symfony 1: connecting to database without using the doctrine or managers

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony1

i just want to know if this is possible. Establishing connection without using the doctrine setup.

```
private function userExist($username){
$con = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnection('doctrine');  

$sql = 'SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE username =\''.$username.'\'';

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

//$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if(!empty($result)){        
  return true;      
}else{
  return false;      
}
```

}

to

```
private function userExist($username){

$con = new PDO('pgsql:host=xx.xxx.xxx;dbname=support_tool','xx','xxx');
$sql = 'SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE username =\''.$username.'\'';

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

//$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if(!empty($result)){        
  return true;      
}else{
  return false;      
}
```

}

i just want to test it if it is possible. if not please tell me why, thanks for the help.

Comment: update: it is possible..

Comment: What happens when you try it?